# vagrant can't run, when i typed 「vagrant up」,there is no response (no error message)!

Tags: windows-7, vagrant

My os is windows 7;

```
vagrant box add firstBox ./virtualbox.box

==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> box: Adding box 'firstBox' (v0) for provider:
    box: Unpacking necessary files from: file://C:/Users/liumeng/vagrant_get
ting_started/virtualbox.box
    box: Progress: 100% (Rate: 687M/s, Estimated time remaining: --:--:--)
==> box: Successfully added box 'firstBox' (v0) for 'virtualbox'!

vagrant init fistBox

A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
`vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.

vagrant box list

$ vagrant box list
firstBox (virtualbox, 0)

vagrant up


// There is no response,no error message
```

I download check virtual cpu tools in windows; ande It's OK;「havdetectiontool」

```
This computer is configured with hardware-assisted virtualization
```

The virtualBox can run normally, Could you give me some idea?

Comment: Vagrant init fistbox or firstbox ? Any how it should print error message

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem the other day.
I tried vagrant_1.9.7_x86_64.msi on my Windows 7 box(CPU=AMD PhenomII).
'vagrant up' went totally silent with no sign of progress and without error messages of any kind.

So I tried older version vagrant_1.9.5.msi and this one just worked fine.

# I don't know whether vagrant_1.9.7_i686.msi works okey or not.